# In POSIX sed, does the period (dot) match a newline in a multiline pattern space?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, posix

In GNU sed it works. For example, this matches two blank lines in a multiline pattern space (created with `N`)

```
/^\n$/
```

Is this standard?

Comment: yes. a newline is a character. on that note, so is a `\0`, but the `.` is forbidden from matching it. GNU does match a `\0` w/ a `.`, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

> [Basic/Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html)
>
> A period `.`, when used outside a `[` bracket expression `]`, is a[n] [BE]RE that shall match any character in the supported character set except NUL.

Many POSIX regexp implementations *(such as `grep` or `sed`)* don't have difficulty matching a newline because the `.` won't match it, but rather because their input delimiter is a newline - and so they simply don't have any newlines in the scanned string to match.

A POSIX `grep` can never match a newline - it is synonymous w/ the null string to `grep`. `sed` is similar, except that a `sed` can perform edits or pull in extra input according to scripted commands, and the results of these may include newlines in pattern-space, even if they can never happen there otherwise. In that case, though, the `.` will match the `\n`ewline.

One thing which cannot be done with practically any POSIX implementation of which I'm aware is matching the `^` complement of a newline. This is because a `\` backslash stands for itself within a `[` bracket expression `]` and so the `\n` escape there means only `\` and `n`. Because it is also generally a syntax error to include a literal newline in a regular expression *(though `pax` is one exception of which I know)*, you cannot do `[^`*`<newline>`*`]` portably.

A sane implementation should handle `"[$(printf '\1-\11\13-\377')]"`, but that limits the match in multibyte scenarios.

There is also: `"\(\([^[:space:]]*[[:blank:]$(printf '\r\v\f')]*\)*\)"` but that's a little unwieldy.

What you can do portably, though, is temporarily swap all newlines in pattern space with some other character *(and vice versa, of course)*, and then match the complement of that other character.

For example:

```sh
printf %s\\n "a a" "b b" "c c" |
sed -e 'H;1h;$!d;x;l' -e '# slurps input to last line - usually a bad idea'   \
    -e 'y/ \n/\n /;l' -e '# transliterates spaces and newlines at once'       \
    -e 's/[^ ]*//2;l' -e '# substitutes away 2cd sequence of not spaces'      \
    -e 'y/ \n/\n /;l' -e '# transliterates spaces and newlines again'
```

---

```
a a\nb b\nc c$
a\na b\nb c\nc$
a\na  c\nc$
a a\n\nc c$
a a

c c
```

There are 4 `l`ook commands in that little script - one for each time the pattern space is changed after the last line is found. Each of the `l`ook commands corresponds to one of the first four output lines above, which are easily marked by the trailing `$` character.

The last three lines are the results of all edits as printed by `sed` to stdout by default. The second line is entirely empty, because `sed` substituted away the second sequence of the complement of the space character, which matched all characters in pattern space except input newlines at that time, and so the second sequence was the entire second line, less its trailing newline delimiter.

Importantly, this works *because* the dot *(or its more restrictive `[` bracket expression `]` alternative)* matches a newline.